# How to submit universal application on iTunes?

Tags: iphone, ipad, itunes, universal

I want to submit application for iPad and iPhone both. first time when i submit application its submitted as iPhone only.

it created for both iPad and iPhone but in itunes its show only as iPhone application [America's best showcaves](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/americas-best-showcaves/id459689507?mt=8)

can anybody tell me how can i submit my application for iPad and iPhone both.

Thanks in advance .... :)

Comment: Check in the itunes connect have u submitted screen shot of iphone and ipad both.

Answer (score 1):

It is done automatically when your binary is generated as a universal app specified as "iPhone/iPad" in the targeted device family.
EDIT:
And you check your icon-72.png file is in its place and at least Default-Portrait~ipad.png file as well.

Answer (score 1):

Beside uploading the images and details you need to set some information on target and project setting check out the images below and do the things .

[image]

[image]

by doing these steps your app will be universal app on app store