# How to submit universal application

Tags: ios, app-store, ios-universal-app

Recently, my first iPhone app is approved. I decided to convert it to a universal app, and since it is a basic application I did it easily. I'll resubmit the app today, but I have some concerns about the process.

Idea 1) Creating a new application on itunesconnect. However, current users of my app won't get update notification and there will be 2 different applications. So this idea sounds really stupid

Idea 2) Creating a new **version** of my current application, this looks good for iPhone side of the app. However, I don't have any iPad app. Defining a new version for a non-existing iPad app sounds weird.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. As I know, one have to debug app on a real device to submit .app file. In my case - universal application, do I have to test app on both iPhone and iPad ?

I really don't know what I should do about it. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975857/how-to-submit-universal-application-on-itunes and this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868743/submit-universal-apps-to-the-apple-app-store,,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should test your universal on both an iPhone and an iPad. If you don't own an iPad but just an iPhone, then if it works well on the iPhone and on the iPad simulator, then you should be OK. But it is still possible for there to be hidden issues. One issue you can have by not testing on a real iPad is making sure all of you iPad specific images and xib files actually work on a real device due to filename case sensitivity. But you can only test on devices that you actually have.

There is no requirement that you test on any device before you can submit the app. Apple has no way to know whether you did or not. Of course it is a really bad idea to only use the simulator for testing since there are so many differences.

As for submitting the app, you must use idea 2. Create an update to your existing app in iTunes Connect. Submit the binary. It will be detected as a universal app. Then you can update the meta data with new iPhone screen shots and iPad screen shots.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Don't we have to build on a real device to create product, that is AppName.app file? When I build my project using simulator rather than an iPhone, it doesn't create the .app file

Comment: No. Xcode runs on your Mac, not on an iOS device. You just need to do an archive build. The only requirement is choosing a device build. You can choose the generic "iOS Device" for this.